# Spark - Python - Get Year/Month on RDD

Tags: python, date, apache-spark, rdd

I've a RDD with two elements (id, date). With following structure:

```
data=sc.textFile("/user/cloudera/dates.txt")
1,01-01-2001
2,01-02-2001
3,01-03-2001
```

I want to transform my RDD into:

```
1,01/2001
2,02/2001
3,03/2001
```

How can I do this? I try to use map:

```
data.map(lambda l: (year(l[1]) + month(l[1])))
```

But year and month are not defined

Comment: `l[1]` is just a string... You probably should be searching for how to parse and format a string in Python

Comment: Or, you should be Sparks builtin CSV reader, not `textLines` and try SparkSQL date functions

Comment: Didn't found any datetime parsing for a element in a RDD, only for dataframes

Comment: `import datetime`... `datetime.strptime`, and `datetime.strptime`... These are Python functions, not Spark functions. The _alternative_ is using SparkSQL `toDate`, as shown below

Answer (score 3):

Try to parse the string date and then apply on each row using `withColumn` and get a new column of date which parsed. You should define your function as a `udf` before to use it.

```
import datetime

def date_time_to_date(input_date_time):
   new_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(input_date_time, "%d-%M-%Y").date()
   return str(new_date.month) + "/"+ str(new_date.year)

udf_date_time_to_date = udf(date_time_to_date, StringType())
data.toDF(['id' , 'date']).withColumn('new_date', udf_date_time_to_date('date'))
```

Comment: Rather than `str(new_date.month) + "/"+ str(new_date.year)`, should probably use `datetime.strftime`

Comment: @cricket_007 why? The OP wants the data in an string format like its orginal format. Also, I've used from `strftime` ind the `udf` function.

Comment: You used `strptime` to parse it. I meant use formatting function rather than string concatenation

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks. I found it. Indeed, I should change `DateType` to `StringType` in my code. As I said the result of the `udf` function should be string not in a date format.

Answer (score 1):

You should read the file as csv and not text. I'm just mimicking it using a hardcoded df in Scala. You should be able to convert it to python with similar syntax.

```
val df = Seq((1,"01-01-2001"),(2,"01-02-2001"),(3,"01-03-2001")).toDF("a","b")
val df2 = df.withColumn("b",to_date('b,"dd-MM-yyy"))
df2.printSchema()
df2.show(false)
df2.select(col("a"), date_format('b,"MM/yyyy").as("dt1")).show(false)
```

Results:

```
root
 |-- a: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- b: date (nullable = true)

+---+----------+
|a  |b         |
+---+----------+
|1  |2001-01-01|
|2  |2001-02-01|
|3  |2001-03-01|
+---+----------+

+---+-------+
|a  |dt1    |
+---+-------+
|1  |01/2001|
|2  |02/2001|
|3  |03/2001|
+---+-------+
```

Comment: It exists any way to do it using RDD?

Comment: @PedroAlves The DataFrame API (and Spark 2) should be preffered when working with CSV and similar datasets with schemas. Cloudera supports Spark 2...